# New column value based on two timestamp columns in df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am using the code below to use an if statement for a column in a df to result in a value

```
def time_delta(df):
    if df['a_time'] > df['b_time']:
        res = 'Early'
    else:
        res = 'Late'
    return res
```

Is there a better or more efficient way to code this?

Basically I want a new column with a value of either Early or Late based on the two time columns relationship.

Thanks!

Comment: np.where(df['a_time'] > df['b_time'],'E', ' L')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below method to create a new column.

```
df['new_col'] = 'Late'
df.loc[df['a_time'] > df['b_time'], 'new_col'] = 'Early'
```

or use np.where

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['a_time'] > df['b_time'], 'Early', 'Late')
```

However, the first method is the pandas way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

**Example**

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['value']=0
df['a_time']=[1,2,3]
df['b_time']=[3,0,1]
cond=df['a_time']>df['b_time']
df['value']=df['value'].mask(cond,'Early').mask(~cond,'Late')
```

Output:

```
df
value   a_time  b_time
0   Late    1   3
1   Early   2   0
2   Early   3   1
```